# Java - Get calling URL without parameters included

Tags: java, http, url, http-headers, request-headers

I'm using the following method to get the calling URL of my service:

```
**request.getHeaders("Referer").nextElement();**
```

But, it comes with parameters used in the previous URL GET method.

Is there a way to retrieve only the calling source URL without any parameters?

Comment: Just remove everything after the question mark?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Better if I could get the value directly from some place where it's already prepared. Maybe some HTTP variable mapped in java backend.

Comment: No, I don't think you'll find such a variable, especially if you don't specify which library you're working with. Anyway, "Referer" is a header that is easily spoofed, so beware of relying on it anyway. There is no reliable way to know which URL called your page and whether that URL is actually useful without parameters.